# Why does Lelouch need geass in both eyes?

Tags: code-geass

In [other question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18787/lelouch-geass-in-both-eyes), it was clarified that Lelouch's two eyes Geass is to show the growing of Lelouch's Geass power and to stop his father's plans. what left of it to understand is, besides the "growing power" is there any difference in Lelouch's Geass demand power from before? I mean, in Mao case for example once his Geassh reached the limit and turned his two eyes he couldn't control it anymore, but in Lelouch case, we don't see any difference in the using of his Geass, so except the inevitable Geass growing power was there a difference in Lelouch's Geass using when he has 2 Geass eyes?

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory about this.

The Geass consists in three stages: 
Normal stage -> Lost control stage -> Both eyes stage.

The point with third stage is that, only in this stage, the user is able to complete his/her contract and become a Code. Lelouch and any other Geass' users will not show any difference in his/her power level or new abilities, since this stage only remarks the new capacity of the user to become a Code.

After watch the anime twice (and Akito once) I think this makes sense and there is not (as far as I remember) anything that contradicts it.

Comment: It's seems you missed big point, in Mao case once he came to (what you called) two eyes phase his ability changed - he could read minds even from miles than usually, not just "getting out of control" so - is Lelouch control ability changed or upgraded in some way?

Comment: This upgrade occurred before Lost control stage. C.C said Mao's Geass got stronger after each use (the same as Lelouch and another users, since this is a Geass' general rule) and, at the point when Lost control stage began, he was able to read minds even for miles from him. As far as I know, Lelouch did not receive any notable upgrade on his Geass after each use, but the point is that abilities' upgrade of Geass users occur between Normal stage and Lost control stage. When Lost control stage begins, his/her abilities has already reached it maximum level.

Comment: Actually, the OP of the question that you linked already said what is the upgrade of Lelouch's Geass: as C.C said, Lelouch will reach a point that even contact lens will not be capable to contain his Geass. So, here is what you are looking for.

Comment: you contract yourself, in the answer you say that  losing control of the geass is a stage and then in the comments you say the fact that lelouch needs contact lens (in other words lost control o the geass) is an upgrade, this "stage" is happening to everyone who has geass, in mao case he can't shut down his mind reader very much like and in lelouch case can't shut the geass in his eyes.